# Selenium ide change values at runtime

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to change the value of global param inside while loop.
For some reason the value isn't changing although I'm inserting a new value.

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>CallTime</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>${OnCall}==true</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>callStateLabel_16@text</td>
    <td>ElapsedTime</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${ElapsedTime}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>storedVars['CallTime']=${ElapsedTime}</td>
    <td>CallTime</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${CallTime}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The last echo gives 1 while the elapsed time is 00:35. How should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

instead of "store" you should use "storeEval", and leave field "value" empty

try

```
<tr>
 <td>storeEval</td>
 <td>storedVars['CallTime']=${ElapsedTime}</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```